# Cannot match last item in list with regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to detect, with a regular expression in Python, this key/value pair:

```
key_title=[a3;d2;g5;a5]
```

Values are a list of elements separated by ";"

...but it doesn't works because the last element in <values> doesn't ends with ";"

I have this python regex:

```
(?P<key_values_pair>^(?P<text>\w+)\s*=\s*\[(?P<values>[a-zAZ]\d;)+\])
```

and this data to match

```
title=[a3;d2;g5;a5] #comment
# other comment
some_key=[j7;k9]
```

Comment: Where does your key/pairs come from, what are you trying to do with it after? It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito I didn't made the file format. Is obvious: [key]=[array]. I need to read the array.

Comment: Which ***file format*** are you talking about?! I'm not following your question or comment.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito I didn't noticed that I need special formatting to write <values> (&lt;values&gt;). Is that the source of the confusion? I'm accustomed from .NET Regex to recover all instances of <values>. I didn't knew that Python wasn't capable of doing it. Maybe that's the source of the confusion?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, I've simplified slightly and made the semicolon optional:

```
(?P<key>\w+)=\[(?P<values>(\w+\d;?)+)\]
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hdmn3s/2/)

Comment: But it captures all the <values> as one single match (list), instead of matching each value inside the key-value pair

Comment: @tutizeri: you can't obtain a single match list with the re module since when you repeat a capture group the previous capture is overwritten with the next. All you can do is to describe all the content between brackets and to split it after. You can also use the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that is able to deal with repeated captures.

Comment: To the reader: relevant info here https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply make the semicolon optional like this:

```
(?P<key_values_pair>^(?P<text>\w+)\s*=\s*\[(?P<values>[a-zAZ]\d;?)+\])
```

Comment: Since is not possible to recover all the matched <values> as in .NET regex, I would pick your answer as the best one, but it fails to match all the occurrences of key-value pairs https://regex101.com/r/hdmn3s/3